# How to select all rows HTML table

Tags: php, html, mysql, checkbox, html-table

I came across a problem which I can't solve on my own!

I have a Table which is populated using PHP/MySQL something like

```
foreach($users as $user){
    ?> <tr id="<?php echo $user['fName'].
            "-".$user['lName'];?>">
        <td> <?php 
            echo $user['fName']." ".$user['lName']; 
        ?> </td>
       <?php 
            for ($i = 0; $i<$count+3; $i++){
                ?> <td><input class="accessCheck" id="<?php
                echo $user['lName']."-".$pagesArray[$i];
                ?>" type="checkbox"></td> 
      <?php } ?>
   </tr> <?php 
}
```

As you can see table would look something like

```
fName lName | checkbox | checkbox | checkbox | mainCheckbox
```

What I need to do is to check/uncheck all checkboxes with mainCheckbox, is there a way to select all rows just from checking this mainCheckbox?

EDIT: How to find class when you select something like input, is there a way of finding a class for this? For example

```
$("input").click(function(){

});
```

Is there a way to find a class for this input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tyr this:

```
$('#all').on('click', function(){
    $(':checkbox').prop("checked",$(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Dfzdh/

Comment: Okey the function works, and i had something like that already, but what i need is to find all ocurences in that row! For example i have row,

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to use jQuery
Look at the sibblings method.
Here is a question close to yours.
[OnClick change all sibling table rows jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232607/onclick-change-all-sibling-table-rows-jquery)

I havent heard about any "onChange"-equivalent function in PHP yet